# Why do seaborn heatmap annotations disappear when I update the plot in pyqt?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5, seaborn

Here is a working example. When it's first plotted, the annotations appear. But when I change a value in a spinbox, it plots the heatmap again, but the annotations don't show up. This is true for any type of replotting, I don't think it's special to the spinboxes. If I don't clear the axes with `self.ax.cla()` each time, the new heatmap overlaps with the old. I have a separate cbar in the subplots column so a new one isn't added each time.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'PyQt5'
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(8, 8)))
        self.ax, self.cbar_ax = canvas.figure.subplots(ncols=2,
                                         gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 1]})
        self.spinbox2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinbox2.setMaximum(8)
        self.spinbox2.valueChanged.connect(self.plot)
        self.spinbox2.blockSignals(True)
        self.spinbox2.setValue(8)
        self.spinbox2.blockSignals(False)
        self.spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinbox.setMaximum(self.spinbox2.value())
        self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.plot)
        self.spinbox.blockSignals(True)
        self.spinbox.setValue(0)
        self.spinbox.blockSignals(False)
        layout.addWidget(canvas)
        layouth = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layouth.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        layouth.addWidget(self.spinbox2)
        layout.addLayout(layouth)
        self._main.setLayout(layout)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        self.ax.cla()
        min_q = self.spinbox.value()
        max_q = self.spinbox2.value()
        self.spinbox.setMaximum(self.spinbox2.value())
        difs = np.squeeze(np.subtract.outer(x, x))
        sns.heatmap(difs[min_q:max_q+1, min_q:max_q+1], linewidth=0.5, vmin=-9, vmax=9,
                    square=True, cmap='Blues', annot=True,
                    xticklabels=range(min_q, max_q+1), yticklabels=range(min_q, max_q+1),
                    ax=self.ax, cbar_ax=self.cbar_ax, fmt=".1f")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any ideas why?

If they don't disappear when you use it, let me know, this occurs on a Mac for me. Thanks